# How authenticate .net core app from angular client using identityserver4

Tags: angular, .net-core, identityserver4

My angular app is running on `http://localhost:4200` and my .net core mvc app with integrated identityserver4 authentication is running on `https://localhost:44312/`

```
https://localhost:44312/connect/authorize?client_id=DocumentationGen&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fauthentication%2Flogin-callback&response_type=code&scope=DocumentationGenAPI%20openid%20profile&state=d9ecb6d546e147569672b85fb8239fc7&code_challenge=W78Reow6OnPtRs36FcieAc1-rUPfHSvE2rHWD9BpBYw&code_challenge_method=S256&prompt=none&response_mode=query
```

when I try to authenticate I am getting this below error

```
https://localhost:44312/home/error?errorId=CfDJ8B-i8u6rBkNAj3HnFY4JfcyXVNdYo37R9IxB3zFzX--WIeR89rnU7XNedmt_AHjo_HCw8Y04yrfDTxNnDud2_P2D_yNvqJyUhQrDp0iB_5njT13pYmY-a0N5jNdgMPYVHVY0hIF0aqx0KCkYJ9O_fga8djacA_78tizfFjWcN7mndsQxepe-Ox1UYdFHd_fuka86LaCL4JVeMA07r1NSG5LIOUv7RabIowsU0JHrbXR3NizS05-cdzsQDmFiVjl1DWfL0M3ba5y4ERSdbDFkLsay8xg4FiapvLCdcirWSkfzXnb3HPmgH9GYaBvMi0CVVQ1xn23ZRNcYTA5b4FO83kFwD-VVNi1u6YKc-PjUvFHw1InpFDXwtkl8zZWU_Iv6hg
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research finally got the answer in this link

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-5.0
```

add this in your startup.cs file in order to authenticate from a different port

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
               .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
               {
                   options.Clients.AddSPA(
                       "client name", spa =>
                       spa.WithRedirectUri("http://localhost:4200/authentication/login-callback")
                          .WithLogoutRedirectUri(
                              "http://localhost:4200/authentication/logout-callback").WithClientId("ClientId"));
                });
```